# Unable to install Nautilus after accidentally deleting it

Tags: nautilus

Using Ubuntu 18.04.4, deleted Nautilus for some reason, but now `sudo apt install nautilus` **says I've held broken package**. I followed similar posts asked here before, but it went in vain. I liked Nautilus, I find no other file manager better than this (don't recommend),

Comment: "*followed similar posts asked here before*" doesn't convey anything meaningful to others. Please **[edit]** your question and mention what *exactly* you tried and also provide the *complete* error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Rather nuclear solution, but it usually fixes whatever aptitude whines about:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f nautilus
```

Check what output the `autoremove` command spouts, it might remove some packages you'd need.

Comment: thanks, after rebooting and a successful system update, I've finally managed to install Nautilus